# Which temperature do I ferment at: the recipe's temp or the yeast's recommended temp?

Tags: fermentation-temperature, lager

So, I'm trying to brew a Mexican lager today. What I've done is taken Palmer's [Cold But Not Baroque](http://www.howtobrew.com/section4/chapter19-4.html) recipe and tweaked it a bit. However, instead of using Bohemian lager yeast, as the recipe calls for, I'm using [WLP940](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp940-mexican-lager-yeast).

Palmer's recipe calls for fermenting at 45°F (and then secondary at 35°F). However, according to White Labs, the optimum fermentation temperature is between 50°F and 55°F.

Should I be following the recipe's temperature or the yeast's optimum temperature? What about secondary fermentation temperature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those temps are close enough together that it really doesn't make much difference which you choose.  If I had to choose, though, I'd go with the recipe.  The temps recommended by yeast manufacturers are very approximate and often too high.

Answer (score 1):

I just kicked a keg of Helles fermented with WLP940, great yeast! I pitched at 46°F and let it ramp up to 48°F for primary. I used [this quick lager method](http://brulosophy.com/lager-method) and the beer was fantastic just 3 weeks later.